# Is there any way to distribute the stream to every parallel execution' s state in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a iterative stream, which has parallelism more than 1. My feedback stream contains some information that should be redistributed to every parallel execution's state. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Could you provide us with more info? From my point of view look like a join operation should solve the problem, but it depends on how it's de DAG defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your feedback source is an upstream of a non-keyed operator you might focus on [broadcasting](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/index.html).

```
feedbackStream.broadcast();
```